# Python crazy mutability

Tags: python, inheritance, mutability

What this code should print ?

```
class Parent():
    class Meta(object):
        classattr = "Hello"

class Child(Parent):
    pass


Child.Meta.classattr = "world"


ch = Child()
pr = Parent()

ch.Meta.classattr = "Oppa"

print Parent.Meta.classattr
print Child.Meta.classattr

print pr.Meta.classattr
print ch.Meta.classattr
```

I've expected following:

```
Hello
world
Hello
Oppa
```

But got

```
Oppa
Oppa
Oppa
Oppa
```

So... i can modify parent class (not instance!) by modifying child class instance. Is that normal ?

Answer (score 6):

`Child.Meta` actually *is* `Parent.Meta` - class `Child`has no own `Meta` class attribute so attribute's lookup rules resolve to `Parent.Meta`. Also since it's a class attribute, any lookup of an instance of of `Parent` (including instances of `Child`) will resolve to very same class object.

Comment: Which is easily verifiable by running `ch.Meta is pr.Meta`.

Comment: Ok, but i've tryed to use deepcopy and nothing changed:

`import copy

class Parent(object):
    class IntClass:
        intclassattr = ["Hello"]

Child = copy.deepcopy(Parent)

Child.IntClass.intclassattr.append("world")

print Parent.IntClass.intclassattr`

the result is
`['Hello', 'world']`

But deepcopy must copy all fields of object recursively, how can I inherit from Parent and change class fields without changing it in Parent instances ?

Comment: From the `copy` module's doc : " This version does not copy types like module, class, function, method (...)". You can check that after `Child = copy.deepcopy(Parent)`, `Child is Parent` evals to True.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to explain what happens here:

```
class Parent():
    class Meta(object):
        classattr = "Hello"

class Child(Parent):
    pass


Child.Meta.classattr = "world"
```

Here you are assigning "world" to `classattr` of Meta. It doesn't matter if Meta was originally defined inside Parent; Child and Parent shares the *same* `Meta`.

```
ch = Child()
pr = Parent()

ch.Meta.classattr = "Oppa"
```

Here you are assigning "world" to `classattr` of Meta. It doesn't matter if `ch` is an instance. Meta is always the same object.

```
print Parent.Meta.classattr
print Child.Meta.classattr

print pr.Meta.classattr
print ch.Meta.classattr
```

Here you are printing the `classattr` of the **same** Meta.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most straightforward explanation is that the metaclass is just a normal object (of type `type`) referenced by `Parent`, and subclassing and instantiation do not copy the metaclass but just create a new reference to it (or strictly speaking actually not even that—it's just how attribute lookup works). So anytime you're storing a new value into `classattr`, you're actually modifying the same attribute of the same object.